# Bind data based on condition in XML views. SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have icon tab defined already. I have to display data in one of the tab's fields based on condition. For Eg:

For the below column, I have to display data based on a condition.

```
if text.type ===1, 
     display text.field1 
else if text.type ===2,
     .... text.field2
else
     .... text.field3
endif.
```

Code snippet:

```
<ColumnListItem type="Active">
<cells>
<Text text="{= ${/TxtModel/AssignType} === '1' ?  }" width="auto" maxLines="2" wrapping="false" textAlign="Center" textDirection="Inherit"/>

</ColumnListItem>
```

Comment: So would this work?

 <Text text="{= {${aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/AssignType} === '1' ? ${aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/Pernr} : '' }  ||
                                                = {${aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/AssignType} === '5' ? ${aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/Ingpr} : '' } ||
                                                = {${aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/AssignType} === '8' ? ${aufnrTxtModel>/WCPL} : ''  } }" width="auto" maxLines="2" wrapping="false" textAlign="Center" textDirection="Inherit"/>

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just added my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50793694/5846045). This should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression binding [contains several syntax errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788791/bind-data-based-on-condition-in-xml-views-sapui5#comment88586066_50788791). Since it's become too long and illegible anyway, better use a formatter as recommended by UI5:

> We recommend to use formatter functions instead of very complex and hard-to-read expressions.<sup>[[src]](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0)</sup>

In your case:

```
<Text text="{
  path: 'aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/AssignType',
  formatter: '.getMyText'
}" />
```

Then, in the controller:

```js
getMyText: function(assignType) {
  const myModel = this.getView().getModel("aufnrTxtModel");
  switch (assignType) {
    case "1":
      return myModel.getProperty("/Ltxt/Pernr");
    case "5":
      return myModel.getProperty("/Ltxt/Ingpr");
    case "8":
      return myModel.getProperty("/WCPL");
    default:
      return assignType;
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [preprocessing instructions](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/fc185952184c48618ef46306a1517f8c)

I am using you have 4 use cases based on `AssignType` of employee being 1 or 5 or 8. Here we are making use of `if/then/else` Instruction.

```
  <template:if test="{= {${aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/AssignType} === 1}">
      <template:then>
         <Text text="{aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/Pernr}" width="auto" maxLines="2" wrapping="false" textAlign="Center" textDirection="Inherit"/>
      </template:then>
      <template:elseif test="{= {${aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/AssignType} === 5}">
        <Text text="{aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/Ingpr}" width="auto" maxLines="2" wrapping="false" textAlign="Center" textDirection="Inherit"/>
      </template:elseif>
    <template:elseif test="{= {${aufnrTxtModel>/Ltxt/AssignType} === 8}">
        <Text text="{aufnrTxtModel>/WCPL}" width="auto" maxLines="2" wrapping="false" textAlign="Center" textDirection="Inherit"/>
      </template:elseif>
      <template:else>
        <Text text="" width="auto" maxLines="2" wrapping="false" textAlign="Center" textDirection="Inherit"/>
      </template:else>
    </template:if>
```

You can also use [custom formatter](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de), where you can pass `AssignType`, `Pernr`, `Ingpr`, `WCPL` in the path, and those will be available in your `formatter` function, where you can write all your logic which is easier to change than this complex xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested binding expressions:

```
<Input id='inputStatus3' enabled='false' value='{= ${/AssignType} === "1" ? "field1" : ${/AssignType} === "2" ? "field2" : ${/AssignType} === "3" ? "field3" : "field4" }' />
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Bernard LeTourneur - UI5 Single Page</title>
        <script
         src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
            id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
            data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize'
            data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax='complex'
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion='edge'
            data-sap-ui-preload='async'>    
        </script>
        <script id='myXmlView' type='ui5/xmlview'>
            <mvc:View
                controllerName='MyController'
                xmlns='sap.m'
                xmlns:core='sap.ui.core'
                xmlns:mvc='sap.ui.core.mvc'>
                <Input id='inputAssignType' valueLiveUpdate='true' enabled='true' value='{/AssignType}' />                
                <Input id='inputOutcome' enabled='false' value='{= ${/AssignType} === "1" ? "field1" : ${/AssignType} === "2" ? "field2" : ${/AssignType} === "3" ? "field3" : "default" }' />
            </mvc:View>
        </script>
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                'use strict';

                sap.ui.define([
                    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
                    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
                ], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
                    'use strict';

                    return Controller.extend('MyController', {
                        onInit : function () {                     
                            this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel({AssignType: '3'}));
                        },
                    });
                });
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery('#myXmlView').html()
                }).placeAt('content');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class='sapUiBody'>
        <div id='content'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```